# How do you catch and change keyboard characters with python?

Tags: keyboard, python, keyboard-layout, xorg

I wanted to make silly custom keyboards, that would translate keystrokes to equivalents in silly alphabets (leetspeek, Cyrillic transliterations, upside-down characters..), but that turned out to be to complicated. Is there a way to write a python script that catches inputted characters and outputs translated strings (because "B" could become "|3")?

As far as I know, this would be done with X11.